# insert csv file into MySQL with user id

Tags: mysql, csv, charts

I'm working on a membership site where users are able to upload a csv file containing sales data. The file will then be read, parsed, and the data will be charted. Which will allow me to dynamically create charts

My question is how to handle this csv upload? Should it be uploaded to folder and stored for later or should it be directly inserted into a MySQL table?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much processing needs to be done, I'd say. if it's "short" data and processing is quick, then your upload-handling script should be able to take care of it.

If it's a large file and you'd rather not tie up the user's browser/session while the data's parsed, then do the upload-now-and-deal-with-it-later option.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you think the users will use this site.

What do you estimate the size of the files for these users to be?

How often would they (if ever) upload a file twice, can they download the charts?

If the files are small and more for one-off use you could upload it and process it on the fly, if they require repetitive access and analysis then you will save the users time by importing the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD DATA INFILE command in MySQL handles uploads like that really nice.If you make the table you want to upload it to and then use that command it has worked great and super quick for me. I've loaded several thousand rows of data in under 5 seconds using it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html